# Group the Response and display the table with heading in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, jsp, angularjs-ng-repeat, response

I want to group the below response and display in a separate heading for each section of the table. can u provide me with a solution for the below code??

Js File has the response of car object:

```
    $scope.cars = [{
      "brand": "Audi",
      "model": "A1",
      "version": "45 TFSI"
    }, {
      "brand": "Audi",
      "model": "A2",
      "version": "45 TFSI Technology"
    }, {
      "brand": "Audi",
      "model": "A3",
      "version": "TFSI"
    }, {
      "brand": "BMW",
      "model": "3 Series",
      "version": "X7"
    }, {
      "brand": "BMW",
      "model": "5 Series",
      "version": "X1"
    }];
```

JSP File:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table>
          <thead ng-cloak>
            <tr>
              <th class=text-center>Model</th>
              <th class=text-center>Version</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="detail in cars | groupBy:'brand'">
              <h4 ng-show="detail.group_by_key">{{detail.brand}}</h4>
              <td>{{detail.model}}</td>
              <td>{{detail.version}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Expected Output is like below structure as the table format:

```
   Model    |   Version
------------|-------------------
Brand: Audi |
------------|--------------------
   A1       |  45 TFSI
------------|---------------------
   A2       |  45 TFSI Technology
------------|----------------------
   A3       |  TFSI
------------|----------------------
Brand: BMW  |
------------|-----------------------
   3        |  Series X7
------------|-----------------------
   5 Series |   X1
------------|------------------------
```

Comment: This needs to be done using jsp ? I am seeing angular js in your code?

Comment: I am using angular js and JSP.I need to display the output by using both

Comment: Did you have a look at lodash? 
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

Comment: No, I am new to angular js